# Previous instances of characters are not erased

Tags: java, jframe, keylistener

It's like if you were in a mirror maze, you might have trouble finding one specific reflections of yourself. So you would have multiple reflections of yourself, confusing you when you try to find that direct reflection of yourself.

Sadly I cannot post an image.......... 
So...

Character is "C"

It goes from

C

to

C C

when I attempt to move right.

```
package WASD;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class WASD extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    private int playerX = 400;
    private int playerY = 400;
    int C = 1;
    private int RESTART = 0; // Three ENTER = Restart
    private Timer timer;
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    private int previousX = -50;
    private int previousY = -50;
    public WASD() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        setTitle("Not supposed to be a painting program.");
        setSize(2000, 2000);

        timer = new Timer(8, this);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        addKeyListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WASD W = new WASD();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) { //TODO paint is only working once, then failing forever.
        //////////////////////////
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 3000, 3000); // Background


        if(C == 1) g.setColor(Color.RED);

        else if (C == 2) g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        else if (C == 3) g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        else if (C == 4) g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else if(C>4){
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY); 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); //Gray pauses for a second I guess...
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            C = 1;
        }
        g.fillRect(playerX, playerY, 50, 50); // Player/
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(previousX, previousY, 50, 50);
        g.dispose(); //Last thing
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent K) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int e = K.getKeyCode();

        repaint();  //timer.start(); does not affect this. g.dispose() is unavailable.
    /*
    If this repaint is used, then the previous locations 
    that the player was at will be painted as well.
    Basically, instead of moving, all instances 
    made will not be deleted. #PaintingApplication

    However, if it is not used, then the CHARACTER will not move at all.

    It seems that the problem is not about 

    playerX, or playerY, 

    instead, it is about the program not refreshing.
    */
        if((e == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e == KeyEvent.VK_D) && playerX<2000){
            playerX += 200;
        }
        else if((e == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e == KeyEvent.VK_A) && playerX>0){
            playerX -= 200;
        }
        else if((e == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e == KeyEvent.VK_W) && playerY>0){
            playerY -= 200;
        }
        else if(e == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e == KeyEvent.VK_S && playerY<2000){ // Easter egg bug 1
            playerY += 200;
        }
        else if (e == KeyEvent.VK_C){
            C++;
        }

        else if(e == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            if(RESTART == 3){
                playerX = 400;
                playerY = 400;
                RESTART = 0; //TODO
                repaint();
            }
            else{
                RESTART++;
            }
        }
        else{
            RESTART = 0;
        }

    }

    @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}
    @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for making such a simple mistake. The problem is in the function "paint". The line

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, 3000, 3000); //Outline of Rectangle
```

should be

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, 3000, 3000); //Actually filling the background.
```